# k6 SharedArray support json values?

Tags: json, k6

So im trying to load a .json file into a `SharedArray` according to the docs here: https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-data/sharedarray/

Right now my "load" function looks like this:

```
export function loadData(dataFile) {
  const data = new SharedArray('dataFile', function () {
    const obj = JSON.parse(open(dataFile));
    return obj; 
  })
  return data
}
```

Which I then load in my test file via:

```
const data = loadData("/resources/api/cloud-pos-check/cloud-post-check.json");
const body = data[0];
```

(data[0] above is the JSON object in the JSON file, it is the only object there in that .json file)

It was failing until I realized that what I am sending via the payload was a JavaScript Object/String and NOT actual JSON.

So I have to do `JSON.stringify(body)` for the payload. Which seems silly because I am opening a JSON file, parsing it to a string then re-converting it to JSON. I guess what I want to know is this necessary?

Can SharedArray HOLD an actual .json value? Or do I need to do what I am doing everytime I need to send an actual .json payload. FWIW If I try to read directly the object that open returns it shows as blank in the console.

Thanks

Comment: `SharedArray`s must be declared and defined in the init context. And it is an array and can store arbitrary objects or other arrays. JSON is just a notation for objects (JavaScript Object Notation). It takes a second to prove or disprove your hypothesis, what was your result?

Comment: @knittl It complained about needing to be an array....i guess the better question is why it can't just store a plain javascript object

Comment: It cannot store a plain JavaScript object, because it is called `SharedArray`, not `SharedObject`. Of course, nothing prevents you from storing an array with a single element, which will hold your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SharedArray`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-data/sharedarray/) can only store a single array (as the name implies). But nothing stops you from wrapping arbitrarily-complex objects or literals in a single-element array:

```
const shared = new SharedArray('dataFile', function () {
  const myobj = { "a":42, "nested": { "list": [ 1, 3, 3, 7 ] } };
  return [ myobj ]; 
});
```

And then access your object with `shared[0]`:

```
const myobj = shared[0];
console.log(myobj.nested.list[1]); // 3
```

For your specific use case:

```
export function loadData(dataFile) {
  const data = new SharedArray('dataFile', function() {
    return [ JSON.parse(open(dataFile)) ];
  })
  return data;
}
```

or even:

```
export function loadData(dataFile) {
  const data = new SharedArray('dataFile', function() {
    return [ JSON.parse(open(dataFile)) ];
  })
  return data[0];
}
```

Note that `SharedArray` instances can only be constructed in the init context.

Comment: Thats basically what i've been using. In my .json files just putting them in an array `[]` block. And then accessing individual "object" sets via `data[n]`. Feels weird but it works I guess?

Comment: @msmith1114 yes, the answer is "`SharedArray` is for arrays and arrays only". Disappointing, but that's the way it is.